# How to drop system tables in phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

Need to drop system table in phoenix.

SYSTEM.CATALOG &  SYSTEM.SEQUENCE

```
drop table SYSTEM.CATALOG;

Table undefined. tableName=SYSTEM.CATALOG
```

select * from SYSTEM.CATALOG is working

Also not able to drop from habse.
(Saying table not disabled exception)

Answer (score 1):

You could drop SYSTEM.CATALOG in HBase shell.

Comment: I tried to drop from HBase shell also .But it is giving table not disabled exception while table is enabled.

Comment: Maybe your metadata of table is illegal. How about try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557742/table-is-neither-enables-nor-disabled-in-hbase